# How to show text with different colors in submit button

Tags: php, html, css

I have this button in my form :

```
<input id="save" name="save" type="submit" style="background-color:#CCCCCC; border: 1px solid blue;" value="Save <?php if (isset($_SESSION['new'])) echo $rows['id'].' u'; else echo $rows['id'].' m'; echo ', '; echo week_day(date('w')).' '.date('j').'.'.date('n').'.'.date('Y').', vk '.date('W');
if (!empty(holidays())) echo ', '.holidays(); ?>">
```

In holidays() part I'm trying to make text showing red on this button but no luck.

EDIT: For clarification, I want only that part of text in red what holidays() function returns, if it is holiday.

EDIT 2: I extended holidays() function to show also flagging days and not official holidays so it can't just show everything in red.
I'm sorry if my explanation is somewhat confusing.

This is what I have tried in holidays() function :

```
if (empty(strpos($Array[(string)date('Y').'h'][$i],'Not official ')))
  $hf .= '<font color="red">'.$Array[(string)date('Y').'h'.[$i].'</font>';
else
  $hf .= $Array[(string)date("Y").'h'][$i];
```

I can't make it to show holidays text in red.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: you cannot do thus inside an input element. conside a button element instead (and stop using font https://html.com/tags/font/)

Comment: I think you will need to add <input style="color: red;".... into your existing button.

Comment: use `span` tag and add it something like this : `<span style="color:red">yourcode</span>`

Comment: Please everybody check my edits.

Comment: @Asif I tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: @Sparky please share complete function of holiday?

Comment: @Asif Problem is solved. Check Ernesto Gonzalez Martin's answer and my comment on it. Thank you mate for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a button type element you can pass html elements inside the value in the following way:

```
<button><span>Valor</span> <span style="color:red;">Valor con color</span></button>
```

Maybe in this way you can achieve the opjective.

Comment: Also you need `type="submit"` attribute inside your `<button>` element so it will submit the html form when it is clicked ;)

Comment: @Ernesto Gonzalez Martin This worked for me. I achieved what I needed. I clicked this as a accepted answer :-)

Comment: @Majid I already had it there. I just replaced input with button :-) Thank you anyway mate for bringing it up.